# Understanding the first Weyl algebra $A$ and $\operatorname{End}_A (V)$

Tags: ring-theory, algebras

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, $V=\mathbb{F}[x]$ the vector space of polynomials. Suppose we have *the first Weyl algebra* $A$, the $\mathbb{F}$-subalgebra of $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{F}}V$ generated by $z, d\in \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{F}}V$ and defined by
\begin{equation}
z(f(x)) = xf(x), d(f(x))=f'(x)
\end{equation}
for all $f(x) \in V$. Let's suppose the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}$ is zero. Could someone help me understand the structure of $\operatorname{End}_A V$? I proved that $dz-zd=1$ and I suppose I would be useful in any of my two questions but I don't know how to proceed from there. I believe I should check an arbitrary $\phi \in \operatorname{End}_A (V)$ and its action over $1_A$, but don't know how that helps.

Comment: Many properties of an algebra like this is in the [DaRT](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/66/).

Comment: But in the DaRT, they just state them and not prove them, right?

Comment: Yes, just as a reference to guide you, it tells you about its properties. This in itself may help guide you to prove certain things. There are ways to recover the proofs for all of them, but it's not exposed in the website.

Comment: What do you mean "don't know if it's finite or not"? If $F$ is characteristic zero it certainly contains a copy of $\mathbb Z$.  Do you mean finitely generated as an algebra or finite type or something else?

Comment: As for "don't know what it looks like," note that DaRT describes it as a very accessible quotient of a free algebra on two generators.  Since it is also a simple algebra, you know all about its ideals.

Comment: I'm just really lost with this question, I can´t see what the elements of $\operatorname{End}_A (V)$ look like, so I can't wrap my head around establishing a bijection :,)

Comment: And about the finite issue, I resolved it. It was about the basis topic but not an issue any more.

Comment: Ah, i did not notice before you wrote $End_A$. Maybe you should write that in the title instead of "understanding the weyl algebra".

Comment: If you think of $A$ as a subring of $End_F(V)$, it's easy to see what $d,z$ look like in terms of matrices.  The transformations in $End_A(V)$ would be those transformations that centralize $z$ and $d$.  Maybe this is the way to go?

Comment: Thank you for your help rschwieb, been thinking of that and also of $1 \phi$ an arbitrary one and the effect of $d$ on it and then $z$ to fully determine it but I haven’t been able to get anywhere reasonable in the end. I do appreciate you trying to guide me in it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}$

$\End_A(V)$ consists of just multiplications by scalars; that is, it is isomorphic to $F$.  The $A$-module $V$ is simple, so Schur's Lemma tells us $\End_A(V)$ is a division ring, and the division ring we see hanging around is $F$.

To prove this, let $\phi\in \End_A(V)$.  Then $\phi$ commutes with $d$, so $d(\phi(1))=\phi(d(1))=\phi(0)=0$.  Thus $\phi(1)$ is a constant.  Now use $z$ to show $\phi(v)=\phi(1)v$ for any $v\in V$.

One insight for working with the Weyl algebra is that $d$ lowers degree by $1$ (in characteristic $0$) and $z$ raises degree by $1$.

Comment: Thank you kindly. Also, why is it important to remark that d lowers the degree in characteristic 0?

Comment: In characteristic $p$, $d$ takes $x^p$ to $0$, so degree drops quite a bit.